# Parallax code behaving differently in chrome (MacOS Only). Not respecting Z position

Tags: css

if you take a look at Sam's code here:
https://codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: #2D112B;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
          transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
          transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
          transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
          transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
          transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
          transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
          transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}.
```

it does not render correctly in Chrome but Safari and FF seem to handle it fine.  T

The Cover layer shows behind the images when it is meant to show in front.

I have tried to mess with Z-index and various other things as I know chrome can be weird about Z-index.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the community. FWIW, cannot tell whether this is the same bug, but I can confirm that this renders differently on Chrome/Windows and Firefox/Windows as well.